# How to disable the backspace key in textarea after spacebar is pressed?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementById("hello").onkeyup = function(e){
            var a = this.value; // to store the value of textarea
            if(e.keyCode == 32){ //if space bar is pressed
                if(e.keyCode == 8){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

I used this code to disable backspace if spacebar is pressed but it didn't work

Comment: What is the usecase here? Why would you want to do that? Also set a flag - you cannot on the same event see what the next event would be

Comment: I am developing a typing test website where the user is not allowed to delete the word which has been typed- which directly means to disable the backspace after space.

Comment: Set a flag when space and clear it when not

Comment: how to add this flag... Please can you write the code for me...It would be a lot of help to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
flag = false;
document.getElementById("hello").onkeydown = function(e) {
  var a = this.value; // to store the value of textarea
  if (flag && (e.keyCode === 8 || e.keyCode === 46)) {
    return false;
  }
  flag = e.keyCode === 32; // if space bar is pressed
  document.getElementById("nodel").classList.toggle("hide",!flag)
}
```

```css
.hide { display:none }
```

```html
<textarea id="hello"></textarea> <span id="nodel" class="hide">Delete not allowed</span>
```